# Specify Download Directory

Tags: c, github, git-clone

I am learning C and am downloading a GitHub repository through code.  This downloads the code to the current working directory (essentially where the C app is executed from).  Is there a way to set the download directory?

Meaning always always have the file download to C:\Data\ProdData\

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  return system("git clone https://github.com/manleyManlious22/TestData");

}
```

Comment: Look at `chdir` to change the current working directory: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Working-Directory.html

Comment: Holy smokes, I had no idea it was as easy as chdir.  Knowing the command to look for saves plenty of time on google, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just add it to your command:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  return system("git clone https://github.com/manleyManlious22/TestData C:\\Data\\ProdData\\");
}
```

Also, I'm not on windows so I can't check the path, but it does work on linux.

With the `system` call, you are running a command as if you were in a terminal. Any command which works in your shell should work there.

Comment: Does it matter if the directory is empty?

Comment: It's probably better if the directory is empty, less risk of overwriting something.

Comment: Should it be "\\" for the directory to download to?

Comment: I just tested locally, it fails for me if the directory exists and is not empty. It did work if the directory does not exist.

Comment: Yes, use "\\" for back-slashes in the command, since "\" is an escape character, you need to double it to get it. I updated the answer.